# Remove left/right "margins" around Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a `React-Native` app. It has a stack navigator defined as below.

```
const App = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Login: { screen: Login },
    ...
    AvatarUploader: { screen: AvatarUploader },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerBackImage: <Image source={require('./src/assets/back.png')} />,
      headerStyle: {
        elevation: 0,       //remove shadow on Android
        shadowOpacity: 0,   //remove shadow on iOS
      },
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle,
    }
  }
);

export default App;
```

When the first screen e.g. home is rendered, it is rendered fine. When from that I go to the next one, header has 70 point margin on each side defined as "left:70; right:70" and those styles are being passed in props to the `<AnimatedComponent />` for my scene. If I remove them with `react-devtools` changing values to 0, everything looks right. Have no idea how to remove those by tweaking my code.
On Android, everything looks good.

What could I do to remove this left/right thing? Presently, may header effectively takes width minus 140 point, which is not good. ;(

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that iOS header container defaults are not good. To fix, needed to add:

```
  headerTitleContainerStyle: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Moshe! Got major problems with an image at header. Turns out that Android and iOS centers things differently. To zero out right container got it right in both OS.